# Piechart doesn't show up in Canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I just discovered Chart.js and it looks amazing! So I tried to follow an example and it didn't work, saying that `new Chart(ctx, options).Pie(data);` was invalid (that `(intermerdiate value).Pie(...)` was not a function). Then I found that the syntax changed in Version 2 so I changed it to what you find below. I no longer get any errors but nothing is shown in my canvas.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/moment-2.10.6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/test/Chart.js"></script>
        <script src="js/test/chart-test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [
        {
            value: 5,
            color: "#44A9FF",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "N/A"
        },
        {
            value: 79,
            color: "#009900",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "On Track"
        },
        {
            value: 31,
            color: "#66FF33",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Done"
        },
        {
            value: 4,
            color: "#F3F300",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Issues"
        },
        {
            value: 7,
            color: "#FF0000",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Behind"
        },
        {
            value: 9,
            color: "#979797",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Abandoned"
        }
    ];

    var options = {
        //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
        segmentShowStroke: true,
        //String - The colour of each segment stroke
        segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
        //Number - The width of each segment stroke
        segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
        //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
        percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts

        //Number - Amount of animation steps
        animationSteps: 100,
        //String - Animation easing effect
        animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
        //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
        animateRotate: true,
        //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
        animateScale: false,
        //String - A legend template
        legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

    };

    var ctx = $('#myChart').get(0).getContext('2d');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "pie",
        data: data,
        options: options
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the fiddle - [Pie chart with Chart.js](http://jsfiddle.net/p2eembtv/)
I made the following changes:-

```
var pieChartCanvas = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
pieChart.Pie(data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example you gave it looks like the syntax has changed too.

It should be

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
```

Not

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "pie",
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Got that from the example found in the docs -> https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/pie.html

Comment: But when I use that I get the following errors: http://puu.sh/lAnIW/825e750586.png

Comment: If I copy and paste what I see in that example I get: `(intermediate value).Pie is not a function` just like I said in the opening post.

Comment: Okay I solved it myself. I went to their website with their examples, checked the sources and it appears they are using v1 internally still so I just got that and now my chart shows up

Answer (score 0):

They also changed the data format in 2.0. If you checkout the sample [here](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/v2.0-dev/samples/pie.html). You'll see the data is like this now:

```
data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
               ...
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
               ...
            ]
        }/* notice you can have more than one dataset, with pie they interlace when you have more than one */],
        labels: [
            ...
        ]
    }
```

Hope that helps.... also I needed to pull the v2.0-dev branch and build it myself to get past one bug that I found in the "released" version, so you may have better luck with that!